# How to set OnClickListener on the ImageView after rotation animation

Tags: android, animation, onclick, rotation, imageview

I want to set OnClickListener on the ImageViews after I make them using addView method dynamically and rotate them in my application. But onClick method doesn't work properly when I pressed ImageView on screen. If I press the screen at the original location of the ImageView, it works. I want to make other ImageViews in advanced at the final location after rotation animation, but I don't know how to make ImageView having skewed Layout. I'm waiting for your help.....

Thank you.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MovingBillActivity extends Activity {
    private String dollars[] = {"dollar1", "dollar5", "dollar10", "dollar20", "dollar50", "dollar100"};

    private ImageView wallet;

    FrameLayout mFrameLayout;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        wallet = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wallet);

        final OnClickListener handler = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case 100: Log.i("kcy", "100"); break;
                    case 50: Log.i("kcy", "50"); break;
                }
            }
        };


        wallet.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                wallet.setClickable(false);
                // Create a FrameLayout in which to add the ImageView
                mFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll01);

                RotateAnimation anim;

                for(int j=0; j<dollars.length; j++) {
                    // Instantiate an ImageView and define its properties
                    final ImageView i = new ImageView(MovingBillActivity.this);
                    switch (j) {
                        case 5 : i.setImageResource(R.drawable.dollar100); break;
                        case 4 : i.setImageResource(R.drawable.dollar50); break;
                        case 3 : i.setImageResource(R.drawable.dollar20); break;
                        case 2 : i.setImageResource(R.drawable.dollar10); break;
                        case 1 : i.setImageResource(R.drawable.dollar5); break;
                        case 0 : i.setImageResource(R.drawable.dollar1); break;
                    }
                    i.setAdjustViewBounds(true); // set the ImageView bounds to match the Drawable's dimensions
                    i.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(170, 67, Gravity.CENTER));
                    i.setOnClickListener(handler);

                    anim = new RotateAnimation(0f, 30f - j * 20f, 170, 34);
                    anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                    anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.ABSOLUTE);
                    anim.setDuration(500);
                    anim.setFillEnabled(true);
                    anim.setFillAfter(true);

                    // Add the ImageView to the layout and set the layout as the content view
                    mFrameLayout.addView(i);
                    i.startAnimation(anim);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "work properly"? I do not see you setting ID for ImageView anywhere. Try adding `default: Log.i("kcy", "unknown"); break;` to you switch case.

Answer (score -1):

Android will run onDestroy() and onCreate() again to perform the orientation change. To avoid this, try to implements onConfigurationChanged() in your activity and don't forget to allow "android:config="orientation" in your AndroidManifest.xml