# OnclickListener for Animated View

Tags: android, android-animation

found many question on same issue.

[How to set OnClickListener on the ImageView after rotation animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743290/how-to-set-onclicklistener-on-the-imageview-after-rotation-animation)

[How to write the onclick listener for a view after animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713020/how-to-write-the-onclick-listener-for-a-view-after-animation)

i also have same issue, any suggestion ?

Answer (score 3):

You ought to write a fresh, concise question about your specific issue rather than just pointing to other questions. The two questions linked to aren't entirely clear.

I assume your issue is that after applying an animation (such as a `TranslateAnimation`, for example) to a `View`, the `View` no longer responds to touch events in its new position. The reason for this is because the `View` hasn't been moved to the new position in terms of layout parameters, but rather it has had a transformation applied.

The solution is quite simple: immediately after the animation has completed, actually move the `View` to the new position. You could set `myAnimation.setFillAfter() = false`, and set a listener to physically move the `View` to the target location when the animation has finished:

```
myAmazingAnimation.setFillAfter() = false;
myAmazingAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                          // Now actually move the View using LayoutParams
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {                    
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                }

            });
```

Another variation is to physically move the `View` at the beginning before animation is applied, and *then* apply an animation that makes the `View` start where it used to be and end at `0,0`.

Comment: hmm,but what about continuous animation? i have a cloud image which is sliding from left to right for ever. i want to add click event listener,it is not working.thank for information view has just transformed not actually moved to a position. BTW is there a way i could add animation listener for each translation ? onAnimationEnd will not help here